# How to load third party libraries that are included in UI5?

Tags: sapui5

jQuery-UI is one of the third party libraries that are included with UI5. But I could not find the way to call it in a given project. My workaround is to include it in a given project folder, for instance `util`, and after registering the folder with `localResources`, I load it this way:

```js
jQuery.sap.require("util.jQuery-ui");
```

Obviously, there is a better way which is to load the file that is already included with SAP UI5!
So how to do that?

Comment: **Important:** third party libs, which aren't visible in the [API Reference](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api) page, are **not** meant to be used in application development. They can get removed in any future UI5 versions without notice. Please do not rely on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the included jQuery UI version like this:

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-core");
```

Comment: [`jQuery.sap.*` APIs](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/jQuery.sap) are **deprecated since UI5 1.58**. Modules should be required via `sap.ui.define`/`.require`. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61534064/5846045

Answer (score 2):

**Important:** third party libs, which aren't visible in the [API Reference](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api) page, are **not** meant to be used in application development. They can get removed in any future UI5 versions without notice. Please do not rely on them.

---

Third party libs from UI5 can be retrieved mostly from the path [`sap/ui/thirdparty/*`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/tree/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/thirdparty).

E.g. for [jQuery-UI modules](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/tree/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/thirdparty/jqueryui):

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/thirdparty/jqueryui/jquery-ui-core",
  "sap/ui/thirdparty/jqueryui/jquery-ui-position",
  // ...
], function(jQueryUICore, jQueryUIPosition/*, ...*/) {
  // ...
});
```

Requiring them with `jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.*")` is deprecated due to uses of sync XHR and global names.